# JavaFX: Select, move, rotate, draw and remove Rectangle with Mouse

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

I'm fairly new to JavaFX and just trying to implement some simple functions. In this case, I want to draw rectangles on the screen by mouseclick. That's how it's supposed to be set up:

- There is a fix (black) rectangle on the upper left on the screen
- By clicking this rectangle, a second (blue) rectangle is supposed to emerge temporarily. This one should follow the mouse then (by MouseMoveEvent, NO dragging! Movement is supposed to be activated just by clicking the black rectangle), the black rectangle stays where it is.
- While the temporary blue rectangle follows the mouse, there should be two options: 1. By rightclick, it should rotate by 90°. By leftclick, it should be drawn exactly where I click.
- The temporary blue rectangle should only disappear when I leftclick the steady black rectangle on the upper left again.

What's working so far:

- Rectangle is following the mouse after the leftclick (it's the wrong of the two rectangles though, see below)
- Drawing the new blue rectangles by leftclick
- Rotating by rightclick

What's not working:

- Every rightclick creates a new black rectangle (don't know why?? There is no such code in my code)
- The first click on the black rectangle already creates a blue rectangle

Here's my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    Point2D offset;
    Node selected;
    Point2D translateStart;

    int height = 100;
    int width = 50;
    int centerX = height/2;
    int centerY = width/2;

    boolean isClicked = false;
    boolean isOnMouse = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        Rotate rotate = new Rotate();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, width, height);
        root.getChildren().addAll(rect);

        rect.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

        root.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            isClicked = true;
                isOnMouse = true;
                Rectangle temporary = new Rectangle(event.getX()-centerY, event.getY()-centerX, width, height);
                root.getChildren().addAll(temporary);
                Node target = (Node) event.getTarget();
                if (target != root) {
                    // event occured on a child
                    selected = temporary;
                    offset = new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    translateStart = new Point2D(selected.getTranslateX(), selected.getTranslateY());
                }

                temporary.rotateProperty().bind(rotate.angleProperty());
                if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                    rotate.setAngle(rotate.getAngle() + 90);
                } else {
                    if(isOnMouse) {
                        Rectangle newlydrawn = new Rectangle(event.getX()-centerY, event.getY()-centerX, width, height);
                        newlydrawn.setRotate(rotate.getAngle());
                        newlydrawn.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                        root.getChildren().addAll(newlydrawn);
                        event.consume();
                    }
                    if(event.getSource() instanceof Rectangle) {
                        isClicked = false;
                        root.getChildren().remove(temporary);
                        event.consume();
                    }
                }
            event.consume();
        });

        root.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
            if (selected != null) {
                selected.setTranslateX(event.getX() - offset.getX() + translateStart.getX());
                selected.setTranslateY(event.getY() - offset.getY() + translateStart.getY());
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't look too closely (generally best to strip it down to one problem at a time, solve that in isolation then tackle then next), just noticed a rather useless code sequence: `isClicked = true;  if(isClicked) { ..`

Comment: Yes you're right, this was redundant code. I removed it now. Moreover, I continued searching for the mistakes and now at least got the steady black rectangle to work. There are only two problems left now: The initial click on the black rectangle still prints the first blue rectangle (the initial click shouldn't yet produce a blue one). And secondly, it still draws black rectangles at each right click (roation ist working perfectly, but I don't get why it draws anything at rightclick, I defined nothing such in code...). It even rotates all drawn rectangles.

Updated code is in the first post.

Comment: a note: working with plain flags always is error-prone (particularly so if the flags are not orthogonal), so be very careful you have the re/set logic complete. Instead you might consider implementing a state model. Aware that's not immediately helpful here, just saying :)